# Validar formularios dinámicos con Laravel

Tags: laravel

Estoy creando un formulario dinámico y a cada `input` los nombro como un arreglo. Ejemplo:

```html
<input type="text" name="nombre[]">
```

Para solo recorrer el arreglo en mi controlador, ¿alguien podría decirme cómo puedo validar estos inputs array?

Answer (score 1):

¿Qué tal así?

```
public function verificacion(Request $request){
    $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'nombre.*' => ['required', 'min:6']
    ]);
}
```

En la expresión anterior cada nombre es requerido y debe tener un mínimo de 6 caracteres. Acá puede ver con mayor panorama la validación de arreglos:

```
<input type="text" name="amigo[1][correo]">
<input type="text" name="amigo[2][correo]">
```

Puede validar todos los correos:

```
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'amigo.*.correo' => ['required', 'email']
]);
```

O bien un elemento en específico:

```
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'amigo.1.correo' => ['required', 'unique']
]);
```